# How to delete only one side of @OneToOne bi-directional mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two columns in two separate entities

> Interview entity

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id", nullable=false)
private Applicant applicant_id;
```

> Applicant entity

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="applicant_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Interview interview_id;
```

**Question is, how do I map this correctly so that I can run `service.deleteInterview();` and delete only `interview` entity record?**

If I use `cascadeType.all` that removes the `applicant` entity. I tried changing this to persist then I get a 500 error saying that the entity will be recreated if the function is called.

Adding `orphan removal=true` ended up with this exception `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];`

I was thinking of assigning `mappedBy` to `interview` entity, however, I am not sure if that would be the solution and also I have reservations as my `interview` entity is created after the creation of an `applicant` entity.

Comment: set the parent/child entity to `null` before calling the actual removing method from the repository.

Comment: Will try that now, thank you. Is this an elegant way of dealing with this? Seems messy as I feel like hibernate should be dealing with this....

Comment: @Mr.Skip this did not work, I am getting the `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];` I have nulled values on both sides.

Comment: @Mr.Skip it definitely works!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use `cascade = ...` and `orphanRemoval = ...` on the *parent* entity (in your case `Applicant`). Using cascades on both sides of the associations doesn't makes sense (for any relationship, not just one-to-one). Think about what cascading does, and what happens when you try to create a new `Interview`. `CascadeType.PERSIST` says the the `Interview` entity needs to create an `Applicant` if the interview object was given an applicant field. Once the applicant is created, it sees that the applicant entity has `CascadeType.ALL`, which means it needs to persist any `Interview` field that it has, so it would again try to create an `Interview`, which doesn't make sense since you've already created the interview.

My guess for why it's deleting `Applicant` is because you have `orphanRemoval` on both sides. Hibernate looks at `Interview` and thinks that because it has `orphanRemoval` it is the parent side of the association, so once you delete `Interview` it thinks `Applicant` is no longer needed, and therefore deletes that record as well.

The Hibernate docs state as much [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many):

> ... Only the parent side of an association makes sense to cascade its entity state transitions to children.

Look through some of the examples in that guide to see how they use cascading in `OneToOne` relationships.

Comment: Will look into the forwarded information, much appreciated.